# WebException Response attribute returns null

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling, httpwebresponse

I'm scanning a single url that has many paths example: `http://url.com/path1` to `1000`.   Sometimes I get a `WebException` but in my `catch` block, it will throw a `NullReferenceException` error if I don't use the line
`if (x.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError && x.Response != null)`

So my question is this: Does code below fix the error or just ignore it?

Error don't have a specific path to error just random like `http://url.com/path10` or any other link thanks :)

```
catch (WebException x)
{
    if (x.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError && x.Response != null)
    {
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)x.Response;
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
           listBox3.Items.add(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: which part that you don't understand?

Comment: I'm scanning 1 url with many path ex:http://url.com/path1 to 1000 but if i don't use the `if (x.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError && x.Response != null)` it wil throw `NullReferenceException` error so is the code above fix the error or just ignore it :)

Comment: I too don't understand the question. I think you need to rephrase it because your English is not so good. No need for negative votes at this point. Just try to clarify it, to let us know what exactly you want. Edit the question, do not write additional comments.

Answer (score 7):

According to the documentation for [`WebException.Response` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response.aspx/)

> If a response is available from the Internet resource, a WebResponse
>   instance that contains the error response from an Internet resource;
>   otherwise, **null**.

So, if I understand your question correctly, then it *is necessary* to test `WebException.Response` for `null`, meaning that your code correctly avoids the `NullReferenceException` rather than 'ignoring' it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is that mean if the site active the return will never null?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ignoring the original WebException when no response is available.  Whether you mean to add these failures to the listBox like failures which do have a response is up to you

Comment: the parts where you have an 'if' but not an 'else'